# Not able to assign selected value to Html.Dropdownlist MVC 4

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

While user retrieves his profile information from database, i am not able to bind dropdownlist with appropriate value.

User's gender is Female. While user retrieves information on a button click, the dropdownlist loads default values as "Male", "Female" and finally "Other". But, i want it to render with "Female and not male. here is my code.

**Button click on the form to retrieve details**

```
case "btnGo":
    IntialStage();
    item = onjLoad.ReadLoadPatientData(controlID["FirstrName"].ToString().Replace(",",""));
    ViewData["PatientCharNumber"] = item.ChartNumber;
    break;
}
```

**loading dropdown value InitialStage()**

```
 IEnumerable<BindindClass> gender = onjLoad.LoadGenderMaster();
ViewData["GenderMaster"] = from c in gender
                           select new SelectListItem

                           {
                               Text = c.Text,
                               Value = c.Value,
                           };
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["GenderMaster"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below sample which i have did to show the selected value in dropdown,

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CountryList"], new { id = "card_country", @class = "donation-ddlcountry" })`

`public void CountryList(string countryCode)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\Country.xml");
            IEnumerable result = from x in XElement.Load(path).Elements("country")
                                           select x;

```
        var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var xElement in result)
        {
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = xElement.Element("text").Value,
                Value = xElement.Element("value").Value

            });
        }

        if (countryCode == string.Empty)
        {
            var selected = listItems.Where(x => x.Value == "US").First();
            selected.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var selected = listItems.Where(x => x.Value == countryCode).First();
            selected.Selected = true;
        }

        ViewData["CountryList"] = listItems.ToList();
    }`
```